# I want to remove status bar for my fragment videoview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which has a videoview, i do not want to change the fragment to a fragmentActivity, however ,i dont know how to remove the status bar for fragments, can anyone help ):

```
public class VideoFragment1 extends Fragment {

public VideoFragment1() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video1, container, false);

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Activity v = getActivity();
    final VideoView videoView =
            (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);

    videoView.setVideoPath(
            "");

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(v.getApplicationContext());
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting a reference to the activity using `getActivity()` method in your fragment and then using one of the following methods?
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 4):

Use this in the activity of your fragment.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for full screen for your Videoview. mVideoViewRelativeLayout is the Relativelayout in which your Videoview is inserted. Hope it works. Also if there is extra content then you have to hide it with visibility gone.

```
  ACTIVITY_IN_PORTRAIT = false;
        ACTIVITY_IN_LANDSCAPE = true;
        mFullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.minimize);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        Timber.e("onconfigurationchanged landscape" + metrics.widthPixels + metrics.heightPixels);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, metrics.heightPixels);

        rel_btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        rel_btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rel_btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rel_btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

        rel_btn.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        mVideoViewRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
        playerView.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            View v = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
            v.setSystemUiVisibility(GONE);
            getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        } else {
            getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
```